# String Result not Showing

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing a programme in Python 2.7. In the code below I tried to delete "0" number in result. After I did it as `replace(str(0),"")` the number didn't show up.

Code is:

```
if karakter > 32:
    sifres= sifro.replace(str(0),"")
    sifres2= str(sifres)
    sifres2 = sifres.replace(sifres[-(karakter-32):],"")
    sifres3 = str(sifres2)

print str(karakter) + " Sayıda karakterden 32 karaktere indirgendi."

sonuc["text"]= "Şifreleme tamamlandı : " + str(sifres3)
```

As it seen in here after the calculations it should show the result as `"Sifreleme tamamlandı: **Result (str(sifres3))**"`

but instead it shows nothing?

Comment: Your code is really confusing because of your poorly named non-English variables. The `str` conversions are entirely unnecessary. The result of string operations is another string. It's not going to magically morph types, so there's no reason to "convert back". I have no idea what's in `karakter` and I can't read your string literal so I have no idea what this is supposed to do.

Comment: On line two: sifres= sifro.replace(str(0),"")

What is sifro?

Comment: If we are talking just about removing "0" from a string, `a = b.replace("0", "")` works. But what is it you are trying to do? Looks like you are trying to grab a substring between 32 and `karakter`? Then `a[32:karakter]` should work.

Comment: can you translate your code to English so that we can help you better, pls?